# How should I write decorators?

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

In my legacy code, I've found two method of writing view decorators.
1st:

```
def require_session(f):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'username' in request.session:
            messages.warning(request,_('You have to login first before you can access this page.'))
            return redirect('/login')
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__=f.__doc__
    wrap.__name__=f.__name__
    return wrap
```

and 2nd:

```
def require_role(role):
    def decorator(func):
        def inner_decorator(request,*args, **kwargs):
            user_role = request.session.get('role','user')
            if user_role != role:
                if user_role == 'user':
                    return redirect('/dashboard')
                else:
                    return redirect('/dashboard/list_users')
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wraps(func)(inner_decorator)
    return decorator
```

Which one is better and more "pythonic"?
Or maybe should I write it in a totally different way? What is your way to write decorators?

Answer (score 3):

These do different things. The first is a standard decorator, ie it wraps a function and returns the wrapped version, that when called does some stuff before calling the original. It is used in the standard way:

```
@require_session
def function_that_requires_session(request):
    ...
```

The second is a parameterized decorator. That is, the decorator itself needs a parameter - in this case, which exact role is required - and so the definition needs to accept a parameter and then *return an actual decorator*, which does the same as the standard version above. That's why you have an extra level of nested functions. So, this would be used like this:

```
@require_role(role_that_is_required)
def function_that_requires_role(request):
    ...
```

As you can see, the decorator takes a parameter.

The other difference between the two is that the first is using a manual way of transferring the name/docstring to the decorated function, whereas the second is using `functools.wraps()`. You should do the latter (although as lvc points out, you can use it as a decorator, which is even clearer).

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle copying the docstring and other metadata is to use `functools.wraps`, like in your second example, except that you can use its return value *as a decorator*:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff

    return wrapper
```